# Cannot update ListView adapter in the Volley request listener in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-volley, android-adapter

I am new to Android. Now I start developing a project. In my project I am working list view with Volley network library. And I cannot update the adapter and list view is showing nothing.

This is my Fragment with listview and Volley request:

```
public class PodcastListFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private int channelId;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list_fragment,container,false);
        adapter = new PodcastListAdapter(getActivity(),new ArrayList<Podcast>());
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_podcast_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
        this.channelId = getArguments().getInt("channel");
        updateListItems();
        return view;
    }

    private void updateListItems()
    {
        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.api_endpoint)+"podcast";
        if(channelId>0)
        {
            url = url + "?channel="+String.valueOf(channelId);
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try{
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    if(status.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.success)))
                    {
                        JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
                        ArrayList<Podcast> podcasts = new ArrayList<Podcast>();
                        if(items.length()>0)
                        {
                            for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++)
                            {
                                Podcast podcast = Podcast.fromJsonObject(items.getJSONObject(i));
                                podcasts.add(podcast);
                            }
                        }
                        adapter.addAll(podcasts);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Error encountered in transferring data from server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Error encountered in transferring data from server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

This is my custom adapter class:

```
public class PodcastListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Podcast> {
    private final ArrayList<Podcast> values;
    private final Context context;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView titleTextView;
        public TextView descriptionTextView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView durationTextView;
        public TextView fileSizeTextView;
    }


    public PodcastListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Podcast> values)
    {
        super(context,-1,values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list_row,null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.descriptionTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_description);
            viewHolder.titleTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            viewHolder.durationTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_duration);
            viewHolder.fileSizeTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_file_size);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        holder.titleTextView.setText(values.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.descriptionTextView.setText(values.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.durationTextView.setText(values.get(position).getDuration());
        holder.fileSizeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(values.get(position).getFileSize()));
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

This is my podcast class:

```
public class Podcast {
    private int Id;
    private String Title;
    private String Description;
    private String ThumbImagePath;
    private String FilePath;
    private String Duration;
    private int FileSize;

    public static Podcast fromJsonObject(JSONObject json)
    {
        Podcast podcast = new Podcast();
        try{
            podcast.setId(json.getInt("id"));
            podcast.setTitle(json.getString("title"));
            podcast.setDescription(json.getString("description"));
            podcast.setFilePath(json.getString("file_path")+"/"+json.getString("file_name"));
            podcast.setDuration(json.getString("duration"));
            podcast.setThumbImagePath(json.getString("image_path")+"/"+json.getString("image_name"));
            podcast.setFileSize(json.getInt("file_size"));
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return podcast;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.Description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.Description;
    }

    public void setThumbImagePath(String path)
    {
        this.ThumbImagePath = path;
    }

    public String getThumbImagePath()
    {
        return this.ThumbImagePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath)
    {
        this.FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public String getFilePath()
    {
        return this.FilePath;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration)
    {
        this.Duration = duration;
    }

    public String getDuration()
    {
        return this.Duration;
    }

    public void setFileSize(int size)
    {
        this.FileSize = size;
    }

    public int getFileSize()
    {
        return this.FileSize;
    }
}
```

My problem is cannot add new data to adapter and so listview is showing nothing. But I already checked response is returning 10 records. What is wrong with my code?

This is the logcat when I run that fragment.

```
02-01 07:42:54.248 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-01 07:42:54.276 29393-29399/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-01 07:42:54.328 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-01 07:42:54.328 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-01 07:42:54.328 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17990: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-01 07:42:54.328 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-01 07:42:54.328 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
02-01 07:42:54.328 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17994: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-01 07:42:54.328 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-01 07:42:54.364 29393-29393/? I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
02-01 07:42:54.372 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-01 07:42:54.372 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 436: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-01 07:42:54.372 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 07:42:54.372 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-01 07:42:54.372 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 458: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-01 07:42:54.372 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 07:42:54.388 29393-29396/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 200K, 12% free 2596K/2928K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 5ms
02-01 07:42:54.404 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 10% free 2789K/3076K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
02-01 07:42:54.412 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 103K, 12% free 2914K/3300K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
02-01 07:42:54.412 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 4.043MB for 1127532-byte allocation
02-01 07:42:54.416 29393-29406/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 4015K/4404K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
02-01 07:42:54.420 29393-29396/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 4015K/4404K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 3ms
02-01 07:42:54.432 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 4015K/4404K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-01 07:42:54.436 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.463MB for 2536932-byte allocation
02-01 07:42:54.452 29393-29406/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 6492K/6884K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
02-01 07:42:54.452 29393-29396/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 6492K/6884K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 4ms
02-01 07:42:54.504 29393-29393/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-01 07:42:54.508 29393-29393/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb79491c0, tid 29393
02-01 07:42:54.516 29393-29393/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-01 07:42:54.516 29393-29393/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-01 07:42:54.572 29393-29393/? W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-01 07:42:54.596 29393-29393/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-01 07:42:54.612 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
02-01 07:42:54.612 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 399: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-01 07:42:54.612 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 07:42:54.612 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
02-01 07:42:54.612 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 401: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-01 07:42:54.612 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 07:42:54.836 29393-29393/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
02-01 07:42:54.836 29393-29393/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14714: Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
02-01 07:42:54.836 29393-29393/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
```

Comment: Have you checked the `logcat`, is there any exception?

Comment: what is the response of your network api call? is it success/failure ? what is the error?

Comment: I just updated the question with logcat and I think there is no error related to adapter and volley in logcat

Comment: My api call is success

Comment: Have you checked the length of `items`?

Comment: put some log in onResponse and onError method. In on response check value of status is it going in the if part?

Comment: My request is responding 10 records . I already checked

Comment: go into debug mode and set breakpoints in getView() method of the custom ArrayAdapter to check whether it is get called.

Comment: getView is not get called. Why is that please ?

Answer (score 1):

Root cause is -

```
private final ArrayList<Podcast> values
```

your `values`in the adapter are not updating with the new objects from the response. You should check that.

add the required `public` method `addAll()` to your own `ArrayAdapter` implementation, you don't have the visibility on private member in `android.widget.ArrayAdapter` so need use existing public API `ArrayAdapter.add()` to add every single element within a loop. But remember, each `add()` will result `notifyDataSetChanged()` which might lead to crash depending on the number of addition.

So the sum up is you need to implement your own `addAll()` in your implementation. Or you can come up with your own method. There are plenty of ways to do that.

### Update

You need to override -

```
@Override
public int getCount () {
     return values.size();    
}
```

Comment: I tried add . It is not working. I think it is not the problem . Cause addAll is working in my previous tutorial project cause I extended ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @WaiYanHein, if you are 100% sure your new objects are getting added to values, then try with my updated answer.

Comment: did you try removing "final" ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `ArrayAdapter` constructor why are you passing -1 ? Pass `R.layout.podcast_list_row` in super constructor. And use the same in `getView`.

```
super(context,R.layout.podcast_list_row,values);
```

Edit:

Pass an instance of `ArrayList<Podcast>` say podCastList in adapter constructor `adapter` in `onCreateView` and in `onResponse` add new values to that instance `podCastList.addAll(items)` then call `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
public class PodcastListFragment extends Fragment {
private View view;
private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
private ListView listView;
private int channelId;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Podcast>podcastList = new ArrayList<Podcast>()

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list_fragment,container,false);
    adapter = new PodcastListAdapter(getActivity(),podcastList);
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_podcast_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
    textView.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));
    this.channelId = getArguments().getInt("channel");
    updateListItems();
    return view;
}

private void updateListItems()
{
    String url = getResources().getString(R.string.api_endpoint)+"podcast";
    if(channelId>0)
    {
        url = url + "?channel="+String.valueOf(channelId);
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                String status = response.getString("status");
                if(status.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.success)))
                {
                    JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
                    ArrayList<Podcast> podcasts = new ArrayList<Podcast>();
                    if(items.length()>0)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++)
                        {
                            Podcast podcast = Podcast.fromJsonObject(items.getJSONObject(i));
                            podcasts.add(podcast);
                        }
                    }
                    podcastList.addAll(podcasts);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Error encountered in transferring data from server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Error encountered in transferring data from server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: can you put some debug pointer and check if `getView` has been called ?

Comment: his getView() does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

Please fill arrayList before send PodcastListAdapter class and use adapter below code.

```
 if (adapter != null)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 else {
     adapter = new PodcastListAdapter(getActivity(),new ArrayList<Podcast>());
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Comment: Judging by the code he provide, it is unnecessary to check if the adapter is null because it will be always null.

Comment: if the adapter obj were null, he would have NPE by now

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I should have posted the fragment xml layout file as well. The problem was I put the list view layout inside swipe refresh layout. That is the problem.

> This is my old xml layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/podcast_list_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_podcast_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

> This is how I fixed it removing the SwipeRefreshLayout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_podcast_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
```